# Microsoft UIAutomation can't move Edge browser window

Tags: microsoft-edge, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I combined learnings from two different sources to detect open windows using UIAutomation and to move the windows:

1. [Detect the opening of a new window in C#](https://www.meziantou.net/detect-the-opening-of-a-new-window-in-csharp.htm)
2. [Move a UI Automation Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/move-a-ui-automation-element)

I can get practically every app window to move (Win32 apps and UWP apps).  Except for the Microsoft Edge browser window!

**QUESTION: Does anyone know how to use UIAutomation to move the Edge window? Does anyone know what is special about the Edge browser that prevents it from adhering to Microsoft's own UIAutomation library?**

Here's my full console app code (required: Add references to UIAutomationClient and UIAutomationTypes):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Automation;

namespace UiAutomationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(eventId: WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent, element: AutomationElement.RootElement, scope: TreeScope.Children, eventHandler: OnWindowOpened);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Automation.RemoveAllEventHandlers();
        }

        private static void OnWindowOpened(object sender, AutomationEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var element = sender as AutomationElement;
                if (element != null)
                {
                    var hWnd = new IntPtr(element.Current.NativeWindowHandle);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Opened: {element.Current.Name} (Pid:{element.Current.ProcessId}),hWnd:{Convert.ToInt32(hWnd.ToString())}");
                    var _windowPattern = GetControlPattern(element, WindowPattern.Pattern) as WindowPattern;
                    if (_windowPattern == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("WindowPattern is null! Aborting.");
                        return;
                    }

                    if (false == _windowPattern.WaitForInputIdle(10000))
                    {
                        Feedback("Object not responding in a timely manner.");
                        return;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Window is ready for input");

                    var _transformPattern = GetControlPattern(element, TransformPattern.Pattern) as TransformPattern;

                    if (_transformPattern == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("TransformPattern is null! Aborting.");
                        return;
                    }

                    // Is the TransformPattern object moveable?
                    if (_transformPattern.Current.CanMove)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Waiting 3 seconds before move...");

                        // Wait a bit
                        Thread.Sleep(3000);

                        // Move element
                        _transformPattern.Move(250, 500);
                        Console.WriteLine("Window was moved!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Feedback("Window is not moveable.");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType()}: {ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a specified control pattern.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ae">The automation element we want to obtain the control pattern from.</param>
        /// <param name="ap">The control pattern of interest.</param>
        /// <returns>A ControlPattern object.</returns>
        private static object GetControlPattern(AutomationElement ae, AutomationPattern ap)
        {
            if (false == ae.TryGetCurrentPattern(ap, out object oPattern))
            {
                Feedback("Object does not support the " + ap.ProgrammaticName + " Pattern");
                return null;
            }

            Feedback("Object supports the " + ap.ProgrammaticName + " Pattern.");
            return oPattern;
        }

        private static void Feedback(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a video showing that I can open Internet Explorer and move it, Chrome and move it, but Edge won't move!

[CantMoveEdgeWindow.mp4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nc7GG-GdAZMlq9FiEJe6xvMwB2_3b2nd/view?usp=sharing)

System Details:

- Windows 10 1809
- Visual Studio 2019 16.7
- .NET Framework 4.7.2 C# Console App

Lastly, I have even tried using old school Win32 APIs such as EnumWindows, MoveWindow, SetWindowPlacement, and SetWindowPos.  The Edge browser appears to be housed inside of an ApplicationFrameHost.exe process window.  When I try to move the window, I get the same result as using the UIAutomation libraries: It "says" it passed, but the window doesn't actually move!

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. It can work well with Edge Legacy in my test. You can check [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owHPH.gif). I use Visual Studio 2019 16.5.4. The references versions I add are [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RxqY.png). You can check what versions you're using. Besides, I use Windows 10 1903, OS build 18362.836 which with Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362, maybe the different versions of Edge Legacy can also make the problem.

Comment: @YuZhou, thank you so much!  It is definitely my system that is strangely causing this issue.  It works well when I ported my code to another device.  This was racking my brain for a solid day.  Appreciate you trying it out and giving me the insight to the source of the problem.

Comment: Glad you have solved the issue :)